# Solve the equations $\tan x=x$ and $\ln x=x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Is it possible to solve the equations $\tan x=x$ and $\ln x=x$ in their respective domains of definition ?

Comment: What do you mean by $\mathbb R^*_+$?

Comment: $\ln x=x$ has no real solutions. Draw a sketch.

Comment: Probably $(0, \infty)$.

Comment: For $\ln x=x$, answer is that there is no solution, because $\ln x <x$ for all $x$. For proof, calculus is easiest. But if you trust your graphing software, put in the same picture a graph of $y=x$ and a graph of $y=\ln x$. They don't meet.  For $\tan x=x$, graphing software will persuade you there are infinitely many solutions. There is the obvious $x=0$. For the others, you will need a numerical method to find good approximations.  (If $x$ is a solution, so is $-x$.) For example, there is a solution a bit less than $3\pi/2$.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/18718/solution-of-tanx-x

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/442332/express-solutions-of-equation-tan-x-x-in-closed-form/4399971?noredirect=1#comment9207638_4399971

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**First one:** The function $f(x)=e^x-x$ is always positive.  Notice that its second derivative is $e^x$, which is always positive, so we know its concavity.  Looking at $f^{'}(x)=0$, we see that $x=0$ is a solution, so that $f(0)$ is a global minimum.  But $f(0)=1>0$.

**Second one:**  $\tan(x)-x$ will have infinitely many zeros since $\tan$ is unbounded on any interval of length $\pi$.  Specifically $0$ is one such solution.

Comment: I think $f(0)=1$

Comment: @ChrisTaylor: Oops that is what I meant! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you superimpose the graphs of $y=x$ and $y=\tan x$ (do this in *radians*) you see infinitely many points of intersection.  Their $x$-coordinates are the solutions.  And you immediately see that one of those is $x=0$.  (Notice that the slope of $y=\tan x$ is $1$ at $x=0$ but then it gets *steeper* if you go in either direction from there.  That implies it can't have other solutions close to $x=0$.  "Close" in this case could be taken to mean in the same period of the tangent function, i.e. between $-\pi/2$ and $\pi/2$.)

The equation $x=\ln x$ has no real solutions.  That can also be quickly seen by superimposing their graphs, and notice that the slope of $y=\ln x$ is $1$ at the point where it crosses the $x$-axis.