# Non Trivial Solutions of Tangent Equation tan x = x

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry

Do there exist non trivial solutions of the equation tan x = x and if they do exist, how to evaluate them algebraically? I graphed it on Desmos and got many random - looking solutions, is there any specific pattern or equation which describes their occurrence and if it does, what is the nature of these numbers? I mean like rational, irrational, transcendental etc

Comment: I'm pretty sure there isn't any way of fidning the solutions exactly.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Expressing the solutions of the equation $ \tan(x) = x $ in closed form.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/442332/expressing-the-solutions-of-the-equation-tanx-x-in-closed-form) Found using Approach0.