# Numerical solution to x = tan (x)

Tags: numerical-methods

I needed to find, using the bisection method, the first positive value that satisfy $x = \tan(x)$. So I went to Scilab, I wrote the bisection method and I got $1.5707903$. But after some reasoning I came to the conclusion that this value is wrong:

1. $\tan(1.5707903) \approx 1.6x10^5$. Not even close to $1.5707903$.
2. Forget for a moment the above. $x = \tan(x)$ is actually to find fixed points of $f(x) = \tan(x)$; $(x, f(x))$ must be in the line $y = x$. [Here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%28tan%28x%29,%20x%29%20x%20from%20-%281/2%29*pi%20to%20%283/2%29*pi) is the plot:
   [image: plot(tan(x), x)]

In $(0, \frac{3}{2}\pi)$ I can only see a fixed point to the right of $x = 4$, therefore $1.5707903$ is wrong.

Here comes the interesting part. If you [go to Wolfram Alpha and type $x = \tan(x)$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%20=%20tan%28x%29), you will see $1.5708$ in the Plot section:
[image: x = tan(x)]

However there is no $1.5708$ in the Numerical solutions section. Wolfram Alpha found $0, \pm 4.49340945790906, \ldots$.

But [if you type $\tan(x) = x$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=tan%28x%29%20=%20x), you will not see $1.5708$ in the Plot section!:
[image: tan(x) = x]

To summarize:

1. Is $4.49340945790906$ the first positive value that satisfy $x = \tan(x)$?
2. Do you know why Wolfram Alpha is showing $1.5708$ as a solution when you type $x = \tan(x)$ but not when you type $\tan(x) = x$?

Thanks.

Comment: [related/possible duplicate](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/18718/solution-of-tanx-x)

Comment: (1) $\tan x$ maps $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$ bijectively onto $\mathbb{R}$. (2) Moreover, $\tan$ is periodic with period $\pi$.   From (1) and (2) it follows that the $x$ we are looking for is in $(\pi/2,3\pi/2)$.

Comment: BTW bisection is not very fast at all, I would suggest you tried with Newton-Raphson with a starting point like $\pi$.

Comment: @AD.: I'm interested in your reasoning but I'm not able to follow it. Could you please explain how from (1) and (2) you concluded that the $x$ we are looking for is in $(\pi/2,3\pi/2)$?

Comment: Bisection would definitively work depending on the choose of starting points they need both to belong in $I_n = (-\pi/2,\pi/2)+\pi\cdot n$ and surround the fixed point.

Comment: @DavidRobertJones Sorry, I am just about baking cookies with my kid :)

Comment: @AD.: I'm having a hard time figuring out your reasoning (I think is not quite right). Would you please explain your reasoning? (from (1) and (2) you concluded is in $(\pi/2,3\pi/2)$)?

Comment: @AD.: For example: $\tan(x)/2$ maps $(−\pi/2,\pi/2)$ bijectively onto $\mathbb{R}$ and is periodic with period $\pi $. But the first positive value that satisfy $x = \tan(x)/2$ is in $(0, \pi/2)$. In this case from (1) and (2) you cannot conclude anything.

Comment: @DavidRobertJones Ahh. Yes you are right!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason you are getting this "solution" is because the bisection method assumes the function is  continuous in the range, *which it's not*. Since the function at both sides of $x=\pi/2$ is $\pm \infty$, the bisection method will always converge to this "solution".

Comment: Nor is continuous at $[\pi/2,3\pi/2]$ however the solution is there.

Comment: @DavidRobertJones - it's continuous on the open interval.

Answer (score 5):

As you see from the plot of $\tan x$, you're intercepting the asymptote, which is not really the desired behavior. Bisection is not the best method to use.

However, if you're required to use bisection, then instead note that $\tan x = \frac{\sin x}{\cos x}$, so, for relevant values of $x$,

$$x = \tan x \implies x\cos x - \sin x = 0$$

The latter function is continuous, and you should get the desired solution of $x \approx 4.49$.

Comment: I like your idea. Now I'm wondering: What function would you use as $g(x)$ if you're required to use fixed-point iteration method?

Comment: @DavidRobertJones Offhand, I suspect $\sin^{-1}(x\cos x) = x$ should work, as long you start the iteration in $(0,2\pi)$.

Comment: I'm not sure since $\sin^{-1}(x\cos x)$ has no fixed points in the interval. Also don't forget the conditions for convergence.

Comment: @DavidRobertJones It should. I'm not sure if it meets the convergence criteria, but the fixed point should be in $(0,2\pi)$, if the solution is in the interval.

Comment: Ah, I know what's wrong... I'm failing to consider the domain of arcsin properly. Maybe substitution exploiting the periodicity of cos will work... I don't know :)

Answer (score -1):

I have a MathLab code, which is based on bisection method; Here it is:

clc
clear
% zeros of equation x = tan(x);
% The roots of equation x=tanx by means of bisection method
% z  represents the root
% epsilon is error
% NR is the number of roots that you want; number of roots = 2*NR+1
% Max is the number of bisections

epsilon = 0.0001; 
NR = 2;
Max = 100;

g=@(x) x-tan(x);

for k = -NR:NR
    a = (2*k-1)*pi/2 + epsilon;
    b = (2*k+1)*pi/2 - epsilon;
    if feval(g,a)*feval(g,b) < 0 
            for j=1:Max
             z = (a+b)/2;
                    if (feval(g,a)*feval(g,z) < 0)
                       b=z;
                    elseif (feval(g,a)*feval(g,z) > 0)
                       a=z;
                    end
            end
            if feval(g,z) < epsilon %error
            z
            end
    end
end

% outputs for NR=2 are :    -7.7253 ,    -4.4934 , 0 ,     4.4934 ,     7.7253

Answer (score -1):

1.57 is wrong cause tan π/2 is not defined 3.14/2 is 1.57 hence not defined and can't be termed as the least positive value of tan X = x..hence the lowest positive value is 4.49 for tanx = x