# $x_n$ is the $n$'th positive solution to $x=\tan(x)$. Find $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(x_n-x_{n-1}\right)$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis, limits, trigonometry

> $x_n$ is the $n$'th positive solution to $x=\tan(x)$. Find $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(x_n-x_{n-1}\right)$.

Comment: Do you see the solution, intuitively ?

Comment: It certainly converges, since there is a root in every interval $[ n\pi,(n+1)\pi]$. Thus $x_{n}-x_{n-1}<\pi$ for all $n$. It seems that the limit is $\pi$, but I can't think how to show it rigorously.

Comment: @GitGud Whoops.

Comment: See this answer: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/18733/312

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**HINT**

Show that $n \pi < x_n < n \pi + \dfrac{\pi}2$, where $x_0 = 0$ by considering the function $f(x) = x - \tan(x)$, which is continuous in the interval $n \pi < x_n < n \pi + \dfrac{\pi}2$.

Now consider $y_n = n \pi + \dfrac{\pi}2 - x_n$. We have $y_n \in (0,\pi/2)$. Since $x_n = \tan(x_n)$, we have $$n \pi + \dfrac{\pi}2 - y_n = \cot(y_n) \in \left(n \pi, n \pi + \dfrac{\pi}2\right) \implies \underbrace{\tan(y_n) \in \left(\dfrac1{n \pi + \dfrac{\pi}2}, \dfrac1{n \pi}\right) \implies y_n < \dfrac1{n \pi}}_{\text{Because $0 < y_n < \tan(y_n)$}}$$
Hence, we have
$$\left \vert x_n - \left(n \pi + \dfrac{\pi}2\right) \right \vert < \dfrac1{n \pi}$$
Conclude what you want from this.

Answer (score 2):

HINT: Sketch $x = \mathrm{tan}(x)$ and think about the asymptotes of tan$(x)$.