# The roots of transcendent equation $\tan(x)=x$

Tags: trigonometry, transcendental-equations

Can we find the roots of equation $\tan(x)=x$.

I once found a formula which gives its roots approximately. Any link will be welcome.

Comment: The only feasible way is to plot the graph of the equation $tan x -x=0$

Comment: See here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/18718/solution-of-tanx-x

Comment: Similar / same question : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/110256/derivation-of-asymptotic-solution-of-tanx-x

Comment: possible duplicate: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/18718/solution-of-tanx-x