# Evaluate $\lim_{n\to\infty}n(n\pi+\pi/2-x_n)$

Tags: calculus, limits, trigonometry, limits-without-lhopital

Where $x_n$ is the solution of $\tan(x)=x$ in the interval $(n\pi ,n\pi +\frac\pi2)$ , $n\ge0$.

Any hints on how to approach this problem with elementary methods in the first place? The answer should be $\frac1\pi$.
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}n\biggl(n\pi+\frac\pi2-x_n\biggr)$$

Comment: @RobertZ This doesn't solve my problem, as I have yet to learn the Lagrange Inversion Formula.

Comment: For the first few orders you don't need Lagrange Inversion Formula. At that page see also the linked questions. There are many useful references (for example https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/18718/solution-of-tanx-x)

Answer (score 1):

$x_n$ is the solution of the fixed-point equation $$x_n=n\pi+\arctan(x_n).$$ For large $n$, this will be close to the pole of the tangent at $n\pi+\frac\pi2$, so this formula can be modified to
$$
x_n=n\pi+\frac\pi2-\arctan\left(\frac1{x_n}\right)=n\pi+\frac\pi2-\frac1{n\pi+\frac\pi2}+O(n^{-2}).
$$
as $\arctan(u)=u+O(u^3)$ for $u\approx 0$ and $\frac1{x_n}=\frac1{n\pi+\frac\pi2}+O(n^{-2})$.

This approximation $x_n^0=(n+\frac12)\pi-\left((n+\frac12)\pi\right)^{-1}$ of $x_n$ is even good for low values of $n$, as the numerical experiment shows
\begin{array}{r|ll}
n&x_n^0&x_n\\\hline
1 & 4.500182389595496 & 4.493409457909064   \\
2 & 7.726657679500967 & 7.725251836937707   \\
3 & 10.904628605797479 & 10.904121659428899   \\
4 & 14.066431410891004 & 14.066193912831473   \\
5 & 17.220885069983172 & 17.22075527193077   \\
6 & 20.371381496613076 & 20.37130295928756   \\
7 & 23.51950358376561 & 23.519452498689006   \\
8 & 26.666089333609268 & 26.66605425881267   \\
9 & 29.811623905294212 & 29.81159879089296   \\
\end{array}